# how to format a uint that's holding a price in ETH on solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

Quick question let say I have product number 1 which its price is declared as 8 eth, is there a way to format it to avoid insering it in Wei on solidity?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A literal number can take a suffix of wei, gwei or ether to specify a subdenomination of Ether, where Ether numbers without a postfix are assumed to be Wei.

```
contract EtherUnits {
    uint public oneWei = 1 wei;
    // 1 wei is equal to 1
    bool public isOneWei = 1 wei == 1;

    uint public oneEther = 1 ether;
    // 1 ether is equal to 10^18 wei
    bool public isOneEther = 1 ether == 1e18;
}
```